# Python: TypeError: QString.__getitem__(): arguments did not match any overloaded call

Tags: python, user-interface, qstring

I am creating a function that uses a dictionary to replace words within a text file i.e. if the 1st word pair is encountered in the file, it is replaced by the 2nd. Further, the function created called when widget in a GUI is engaged by user. So the functions created all exists within a ui class. (hope this makes sense). I’m using python

The dictionary looks like this (dictlist = {'test':'rest', 'happy':'sad', 'big':'small'}). The function works fine when written directly in python editor, but when I copy it to the translated .ui code, I get the below error. Can anyone advise on why this is happening. I’m new to this, so hope my explanation makes sense.

```
line = rpairs(line, dictlist)
line 1486, in rpairs
temp = temp.replace(key, dictlist[key])
TypeError: QString.__getitem__(): arguments did not match any overloaded call:
overload 1: argument 1 has unexpected type 'QString'
overload 2: argument 1 has unexpected type 'QString'
```

---

```
def temp(self):
    import string
    global filename
    global mytemp
    dictlist = self.lineEdit_dict.text()
    filename2 = self.lineEdit_outputfilename.text()

    f1 = open(filename, 'r')      
    f2 = open('filename2', 'w')

    def  rpairs (temp, dictlist):
        for key in dictlist:
            temp = temp.replace(key, dictlist[key])
        return temp

    for line in f1:
        line = rpairs(line, dictlist)
        f2.write(line)
    f2.close()
    return mytemp
```

Comment: Are you trying to construct `dictlist` as a dictionary from reading `self.lineEdit_dict.text()` ?...Or you have it already in your program code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you initialized `dictlist` with a QString not a `dict`:

```
dictlist = self.lineEdit_dict.text()
```

while you tried to access to it as a `dict`: `dictlist[key]`

You have also many other problems like `f2 = open('filename2', 'w')` should be `f2 = open(filename2, 'w')`

Comment: @ Marco. Many thanks for your response. I've since corrected the type in the open statement.

Comment: @Marco. Regarding the dictlist question/comment, as I am new to this, I do not understand what you mean by I initialized dictlist with a QString not a dict, and tried to access it as a dict. Do you have any suggestions as to how I can fix this issue? I do not have a strong understanding of QString.

Comment: @bigbrother: Regarding the dictlist question/comment, as I am new to this, I do not understand what you mean by I initialized dictlist with a QString not a dict, and tried to access it as a dict. Do you have any suggestions as to how I can fix this issue? I do not have a strong understanding of QString.

Comment: sorry, meant @bigOTHER :)

Comment: @sren `self.lineEdit_dict.text()` is a text , a `QString` not `dict` , you can't access it by keys

Comment: Highly appreciate your response. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: @Sren, you will see the sign of OK on my answer score, mark it